# Geometric unfolding of a difference equation

Tags: reference-request, difference-equations

Does anyone know a link to the (superb) slides of a talk given by Zeeman in 1996, I think (with same title as this question)?  It used to be at www.math.utsa.edu/ecz/gu.html .

Comment: From poking around on the internet archive wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/*/www.math.utsa.edu/ecz/gu.html it seems that the site was later hosted by D. Gokhman at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%E2%88%BCgokhman/ecz/gu.html (broken link now).  Perhaps you might write to Gokhman (website here http://zeta.math.utsa.edu/~gokhman/index.cgi ) and see if he still has a copy?